# Name for the "other term" in a derived exact couple

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences

I'm building a spectral sequence using an exact couple $D^1 \to D^1 \to E^1 \to D^1$, with $k$th derived exact couple $D^k \to D^k \to E^k \to D^k$. In this case, I happen to have more information about the $D^k$ piece than the $E^k$ piece, but I'm struggling to find references for facts I think are true relating information in $D^k$ to the whole spectral sequence, largely because $d_k$ already has a meaning in this context and Google can't tell the difference.

Is there a common name for the $D^k$ piece of a derived exact couple?

Comment: I’m aware only of the “rear” D and the “front” E.